# C Programming - How to read a portion of a file from specific start line and end line

Tags: c, file, child-process

I am working on a program where a user enters a number (1, 2, or 4), and then the program creates that many child processes to add the numbers in a large text file (1000-1000000 lines). Each line has 3 digits followed by a space and newline character. I need each child process to take a specific block of the code (i.e. for a file with 1000 lines and 4 child processes, child1 does lines 1-250, child2 does lines 251-500, etc..) adds them up and returns them to the parent. I am wondering if there is an easy way to have the child only read those specific lines of the file? Right now I have each child going through each line of the file and only adding their specified block. Each child calls this function to add the numbers from its block of the file:

```
int calculateTotal(char name[50], int startLine, int endLine)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(name, "r");
    int total = 0;
    int lineNumber = 1;

    if ( file != NULL )
    {
      char line [ 5 ];
      while ( fgets ( line, sizeof(line), file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
      { 
         int nextNum = atoi(line);
         if(nextNum != 0)
         {
             if(lineNumber >= startLine && lineNumber <= endLine)
             {
                total += nextNum;
             }

             lineNumber++;
         }

      }
      fclose ( file );
    }
   return total;
}
```

My hope is to only have the child read its specific block and then close the file and return the value. Is there a function or simple way to achieve this (Reading a file from a specific start line and stopping at a specific end line without having to read the whole file each time)?

Comment: No, "line" isn't something that exist on that level. If it's important, then you need to create an index over at which bytes which lines start first.

Comment: It does say right there in the question that each line has the same number of characters. So you could seek to 5*(linenumber-1) and start reading. And you could have each process check its final position after the loop, and abort if it didn't end up at the expected offset. Or, forget the "check and abort" scheme, just pick a byte offset for each process to stop at, and stop when you get to it, regardless of whether it's exactly the right number of lines; if you handle the boundary cases correctly, it'll all add up.

Comment: `lineNumber = startLine;  fseek(file, 5 * (startLine - 1), SEEK_SET);` before the loop, if each line is exactly 5 chars and you're counting from 1 (rather than 0).  If the lines vary in length, though, then you have to count lines from the beginning of the file to find the right one.  Also, you should check for errors from `fseek` of course.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri that worked perfect!